# Google Table Search Date an Set Value in different row

Tags: date, find, compare

In Google Sheets, when the sheet opens I need to check if the Date in Row "E" is today or older than today.

If this condition is true I need to write "DONE" in Column "B". I was able to script this so far on startup.

But this function doesn´t match the correct row. It is still not working for me :(

```
function Statuspruefen(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(new Date()).getValue();
  var daterange = sheet.getRange("E2:E").getValues()
  for(var i=0; i<daterange.length; i++) {
    if(new Date(daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) <= date.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
      var today_row = (i+3);
      var today_set = sheet.getRange("B2"-today_row).setValue("DONE"); 
    }
  }
```

[image: Example Table]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :)

```
var sheet     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var date      = sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(new Date()).getValue();
var daterange = sheet.getRange("E2:E").getValues()
for(var i=0; i<daterange.length; i++) {
  if(new Date(daterange[i]).setHours(0,0,0,0) <= date.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
      var today_row = (i+2);
      var today_set = sheet.getRange("B2"+today_row).setValue("DONE");
    }
}
```